# Issue using Javascript to copy elements and write to next row

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript to add a new row. Copies all the elements from the dropdown and writes it to the next row.

Its working fine, but optgroup is missing. Need suggestion on how to add optgroup label to the new row.

```js
function addNewRow()
    {
  var RowId =1000;
        var select1Length = document.getElementsByName("catsndogs")[0].options.length
        var tbody = document.getElementById("animals").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

        var row = document.createElement("TR");

        var cell1 = document.createElement("TD");
        var cell2 = document.createElement("TD");
        var cell3 = document.createElement("TD");
        var html = '<SELECT NAME="catsndogs" id="'+RowId+'" class="textbg">';

        for(i=0;i<select1Length;i++) 
        {
            html = html + '<option value="'+document.getElementsByName("catsndogs")[0].options[i].value+'">'+document.getElementsByName("catsndogs")[0].options[i].text+'</option>';
        }

        html = html + '</SELECT>';
        cell1.innerHTML = html;
        cell2.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        cell3.innerHTML = ' [<a href="javascript:deleteRow('+RowId+');" >-Remove</a>]';

        row.appendChild(cell1);
        row.appendChild(cell2);
        row.appendChild(cell3);

        tbody.appendChild(row);
        RowId++;
    }
```

```html
<table id="animals">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="catsndogs">
        <option>Select</option>
        <optgroup label="Cats">
          <option>Tiger</option>
          <option>Leopard</option>
          <option>Lynx</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Dogs">
          <option>Grey Wolf</option>
          <option>Red Fox</option>
          <option>Fennec</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<a href="javascript:addNewRow();">+ Add New Row</a>
```

Comment: If you run this code on the html you have provided, what is the value of select1length?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/siveziboya/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: _“but optgroup is missing”_ - well you are not _creating_ any in your code, so where do you expect them to magically come from …?

Comment: yes, that's what I said... I need suggestions

Comment: @dazzle Have you tried the below solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping through you can use clone node function and then modify its id and class name.

[Clone Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

```
var cln = select1.cloneNode(true);
cln.id = RowId;
cln.className = "textbg";
```

```js
  var RowId =1000;
function addNewRow()
    {
        var select1 = document.getElementsByName("catsndogs")[0];
         var cln = select1.cloneNode(true);
         //console.log(cln);
         cln.id = RowId;
         cln.className = "textbg";
        var tbody = document.getElementById("animals").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

        var row = document.createElement("TR");

        var cell1 = document.createElement("TD");
        var cell2 = document.createElement("TD");
        var cell3 = document.createElement("TD");
        cell2.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        cell3.innerHTML = ' [<a href="javascript:deleteRow('+RowId+');" >-Remove</a>]';

        cell1.appendChild(cln);
        row.appendChild(cell1);
        row.appendChild(cell2);
        row.appendChild(cell3);

        tbody.appendChild(row);
        RowId++;
    }
```

```html
<table id="animals">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name="catsndogs">
        <option>Select</option>
        <optgroup label="Cats">
          <option>Tiger</option>
          <option>Leopard</option>
          <option>Lynx</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Dogs">
          <option>Grey Wolf</option>
          <option>Red Fox</option>
          <option>Fennec</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<a href="javascript:addNewRow();">+ Add New Row</a>
```